# UICollectionView Horizontal Scroll with Horizontal Alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout

I would like to have a paged `UICollectionView`, with each page displaying cells from left to right. What I can achieve now with classic `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and

```
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

The result is the following :

```
      page 1             page 2
 cell 1 | cell 3 || cell 5 | cell 7
 cell 2 | cell 4 || cell 6 | cell 8
```

What I would like to achieve now is:

```
      page 1             page 2
 cell 1 | cell 2 || cell 5 | cell 6
 cell 3 | cell 4 || cell 7 | cell 8
```

I would like to know if there is simpler solution than creating my own flow controller ? Or if not, is there some place where I can see the source code for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which is not so different of what I want ?

Comment: Although the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495922/1671176) is correct but the suggested sample code does not work. Below is the sample code I developed that works fine. https://github.com/siddharth-paneri/HoizontalCollectionViewLayout

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally made my own layout subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout : I replace each cell's collectionViewAttributes with the corresponding one if it was a classic collectionViewFlowLayout, using a little bit of maths.

It now fits my needs, and could be useful for someone else, so here is my code:
https://github.com/philippeauriach/fullyhorizontalcollectionview

Comment: It does not work.

It is random order of numbers. Only first cell in each row is right,

e.g  Row#1  0 |  28 | 22 | 16 | 10 | 4 | 32
       Row#2  7 | 1 | 29 | .. . . . . . .