# Tableview-like animations within a collectionview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView, but am using it somewhat like a TableView. I would like to animate cells away by having them animate away to the left and new cells animate in from the right. With the `UITableView`, I could just `UITableViewRowAnimation.Right` animation while inserting / removing cells. How might one go about performing something like this with a `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Like Springboard? How many cells are we talking about here? Do you just want the animation or do you want the rest of the tableView functionality?

Comment: I want the animation, so I would like to add cells in from the right while removing cells to the left.

Comment: maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301762/uicollectionview-horizontal-scroll-horizontal-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no native implementation of such animations in `UICollectionView`.
You can implement them by creating a `UICollectionViewLayout` (or `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`) subclass and overriding these two methods:

```
// This set of methods is called when the collection view undergoes an animated transition such as a batch update block or an animated bounds change.
// For each element on screen before the invalidation, finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingXXX will be called and an animation setup from what is on screen to those final attributes.
// For each element on screen after the invalidation, initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingXXX will be called an an animation setup from those initial attributes to what ends up on screen.

func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?

func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

i.e. `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath` has to return `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the element that is being added, with position (`attributes.center` or `.frame.origin`) from which it will be animated into its position within the table.

Note that `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` also has `alpha`, `transform` and several more parameters you can use to tweak the animation.