# Indefinite width horizontal Scroll view to display images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimage

new to iOS development. I'll explain the core purpose, the app should display an array of images on a horizontally scrolling view, these images will be loaded from the app documents itself. But the number of images stored in the app may vary from user to user. So,
I want to create a horizontally scrolling view (`UIScrollView`/`UITableView`) which can hold `UIImage`. I want to change the width of the view as more images are read, but increasing the width of a `UIScrollView` wouldn't add a `UIImage` placeholder for the new images.
OR
Should I try with `UITableView`, any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to start a UIScrollView, add it to your ViewController and write something like this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.pictures.count * 170 + 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Where the 170 for me is the width of the image + 10 (like to have some space between them). The +10 afterwards is 10px after my images too (end of the UIScrollView).

Later, to put on those images you can do

```
for (int x = 0; x < self.pictures.count; x++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
        imageV.frame = CGRectMake(10 + x * 170, 10, 160, 120);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageV];
    }
```

Replace the imageNamed with your own image name or something like that...

This is only for about max 20 pictures, if you have a lot of pictures then I would suggest using a collection. multiple threads have started about those...

Comment: Thank You so much :), I think i'll have to go with collection view !

Answer (score 1):

Use `UICollectionView` instead of `UIScrollView`.

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301762/uicollectionview-horizontal-scroll-horizontal-layout) link.

Here using collectView is easy as it has delegate method same as `UITableView`.

Comment: Trying Collection view, hopefully it will suit my requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use icarousel in ios https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

There are many types to choose from.

Hope that might help you !!!