# Last horizontal collectionview cell is half displeyed

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have horizontal CollectionView and when i start the app last image in my gallery was only half-displayed. How to fix that?

Comment: The contentView frame is probably bigger than the CollectionView frame.
Can you provide some code?

Comment: I have to set the size of the cells that have to do with the width of the screen. What code do you need, I have the standard codes for collectionView. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45459605/5032981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution it so add some bottom "inset" value.

To do that

1. In your xcode's "utility area" click on "size inspector" tab
2. Then refer the image below

[image: xcode's ScrollView]

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar issue and what helped me is to set minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt and minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The contentView frame is probably bigger than the CollectionView frame.

Let's say you want the collectionView to display 5 cells...

#### On viewDidLoad:

```
let cvWidth = collectionView.frame.width
let cvHeight = collectionView.frame.height
let cellEdge = cvWidth / 5
let contentSize = cellEdge * CGFloat(numberOfCells)

collectionView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentSize, height: cvHeight)
```

Don't forget to set your **numberOfCells** value

If you have some space between cells, you should set cellEdge this way:

```
let cellEdge = cvWidth / 5 + space
```

#### Edit - about UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout:

To set the space between cells and sections first add the UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate to the ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

than you can set the interspace, line spacing and inset via this functions:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: How to set space and numberOfCells?

Comment: You have an array of images right? You can set numberOfCells = arrayOfImage.count @JoeDominguez

Comment: You can read about cell spacing and UICollectionViewFlowLayout here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r  @JoeDominguez

Comment: and how to set Space?

Comment: still do not know how to set space, i tried whit let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0