# iOS 9 Swift 2: horizontally scrollable views? Facebook's "suggested friends/groups"

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, swift2

I am writing an iOS app in Swift 2 using Xcode 7.

I want to display a set of a user's trophies. For this, I am imagining a horizontally scrollable display as each trophy image is small, but users can have more trophies that fit across a screen.

You can see a Sketch example here: i.stack.imgur.com/VtpEc.png

I first thought that I could use a UIScrollableView, but I don't think this will work because user's are NOT supposed to be able to zoom into these trophies. BUT, if UIScrollView is the way to go, then how do I go about implementing it horizontally and without zoom? The most similar feature in an app that I have found is in Facebook's iOS app. Facebook uses these "horizontally scrollable views" for suggested friends/groups.

You can see what I am talking about in this screenshots: [Facebook Horizontal Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HKBl.png)

This feature also seems to be built in to Apple's iOS. When choosing which action to perform, users are presented with a "horizontally scrollable list" of apps to choose from.

See what I'm talking about here: [built in iOS horizontal scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U86X.png)

I would appreciate any help that anyone can offer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using a `UICollectionView` with an horizontal flow layout.

This more detailed answer might help you to figure out how to implement it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19435898/5741377

Comment: UICollectionView is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I appreciate the help!