# UICollectionView custom horizontal paging layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[![collectionview example][1]][1]

I am trying to emulate this behavior using a collection view. I have started by working with this method and it has gotten me closer.  Although as I swipe further and further right on my horizontal paging CollectionView, the content shifts further and further left. Also the spacing between the cells is off.   I believe it requires a custom layout, but am not sure.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 20, height: collectionView.frame.height - 20)

}
```

Comment: what is the actual question here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it depends on 3 factors 
1) Section Insets
2) Cell Spacing
3) Cell Size

Any change in each you have to change others
for your case

1) Set left & right with 20

[image]

2) set cell spacing to 10

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
}
```

3) Set cell size

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 1.15 ,height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

4) this will center cell in screen

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width / 1.15 + cellSpacing ;

    let currentOffset:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    let targetOffset:CGFloat = targetContentOffset.memory.x
    var newTargetOffset:CGFloat = 0;

    if targetOffset > currentOffset
    {
        newTargetOffset = ceil(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        newTargetOffset = floor(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;
    }

    if newTargetOffset < 0
    {
        newTargetOffset = 0
    }
    else if newTargetOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width
    {
    newTargetOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width;
    }

    targetContentOffset.memory.x = currentOffset

    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0), animated: true)

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301762/uicollectionview-horizontal-scroll-horizontal-layout

Comment: how did you come up with 1.15?

Comment: it's about 85% of collectionView width

Comment: thanks its working well now. my only thing now is when you swipe on the cells, they gradually move further and further left. The text label isn't fully visible as half of the cell becomes hidden.  Any tips on how I can have the cells reload at the same position or is that counter to this entire setup?

Comment: please check edited answer i've added the solution to cells shifting left

Comment: thanks again man, so your centering it after its done accelerating

Comment: appreciate it my last question is how do the section insets and minimum spacing relate? don't quite understand the relationship between the 20 in section insets and the 10 on minimum

Comment: This is the space before first cell which will be cell spacing (10) + the part that will be shown from the previous cell if it has.

Comment: ok so if I made my left inset 23 and right 18,  what should i make my minimum line and interim spacing? sorry just didn't quite get it

Comment: so perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a bit @Mohamed's solution and it worked perfectly for me:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let cellSpacing: CGFloat = self.collectionView(self.collectionView, layout: self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt: 0)
    let pageWidth: CGFloat = self.pageWidth + cellSpacing

    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let targetOffset = targetContentOffset.pointee.x
    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = currentOffset

    var pageNumber = 0
    if targetOffset > currentOffset {
        pageNumber = Int(ceil(currentOffset / pageWidth))
    }
    else {
        pageNumber = Int(floor(currentOffset / pageWidth))
    }

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: pageNumber, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```