# Create Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiscrollview

I want to know how to create a horizontal scroll view in Swift. I also want to know how to add buttons to the scroll view. An excellent example of what I'm essentially asking for is in the game "Cut the Rope."

[image]

In the picture you're presented with a picture (which you can click on) of a "fabric box." There are other different types of boxes that, with scrolling, you can access them. How would I do something similar to this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)?  It seems like this would be perfect, with reusable cells that look similar

Comment: check this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636652/uicollectionview-custom-horizontal-paging-layout/37638974

Comment: @MohamedMostafa Thank you so much That helped a ton!

Comment: Your tags already indicate that you are using Swift. No need to add it to the title.